# Terminating the Terminal process for a particular outcome

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, process

for example consider the following situation::

I need to print some numbers randomly one after the other with a time interval of 5 seconds between each, and I need to terminate the terminal process of printing numbers if i encounter an output of '2'. Is it possible.

I know I could do the same in c, c++, java, etc. etc,. But I would like to do it using bash script.

Note:: If only 'after' I encounter an 'output' of '2'(or anything) then the process needs to be terminated, I stress this because 'I need to terminate the terminal process for a particular outcome'.

Answer (score 1):

a bash shell knows its parent process, so you could do:

```
(( number == 2 )) && kill $PPID
```

ref: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `if` statement to do that:

```
# your file reading code goes here, make sure $output is set
if [ $output -eq 2 ]; then return; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to kill the shell from which you run the script. This is a bit tricky as running a script will spawn another shell, and the trivial methods of killing it (`kill -9 $$` or  `exit`) will work on the *spawned* shell, not the one invoked by the terminal.

The only reliable way I found of doing so is to *source* your script instead of running it. So instead of:

```
bash script.sh
```

do:

```
. script.sh
```

this will cause stuff to run in the invoking shell, not the spawned one.

The script itself is easy as seen in the other answer:

```
while true; do sleep 1; number=$RANDOM; echo $number; if [ 2 = 2 ]; then exit; fi; done
```

Actually if you run this as a one-liner in your current shell, it *will* close the terminal when it sees a value of 2.

You didn't say where the random numbers will come from; I used the RANDOM bash built-in which outputs integers in the range 0-32767.